# Changing 'likert' standard texts

Tags: r, plot, likert

I don't know how to change the standard texts on plots created using the likert package.

To make it easy, i will just provide the sample data, as the solution probably will be the same.

```
library(likert)

data(pisaitems) 

items28 <- pisaitems[, substr(names(pisaitems), 1, 5) == "ST24Q"] 

l28 <- likert(items28) 

plot(l28)
```

The output should be as the picture below, and what i want to change are the words "Response" and "Percentage."

[image: Output]

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I did not know the `likert` package but, it seems that its function `plot`, is based on `ggplot2`, so you can modify the options in `ggplot2` way:

```
plot(l28) +
  labs(
    x = "Another lab",                          # here you manage axis
    y = "My lab"                                # also here ("inverted "because
                                                # it seems plot has coord_flip option)
  ) + guides(fill=guide_legend("My e title"))   # here you manage the title of the legend
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.